# Не отрабатывает сравнение по времени в MySQL через PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, дата, carbon

```
$session = DB::table('test_sessions')
    ->select('id as session_id')
    ->where('test_sessions.test_id', '=', $request->get('test_id'))
    ->where('test_sessions.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->whereDate('test_sessions.end_at', '>=', Carbon::now('Europe/Moscow')) // Условие не отрабатывает.
    ->get();
```

Я все равно получаю запись, хотя время end_at уже вышло. Если заменить `Carbon::now('Europe/Moscow')` на `NOW()`, тот же результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

end_at - поле типа `datetime`;

Comment: покажите сгенерированный запрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Carbon::now('Europe/Moscow')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')`  так правильно, в первом случае у вас объект Карбон, база явно о таком формате времени не знает

Comment: Спасибо большое, сработало!

Answer (score 1):

Можно также использовать хелперы now(), today()

```
->whereDate('test_sessions.end_at', '>=', now('Europe/Moscow'))
```

В этом случаи также все должно работать;